# Moodle: upload and analys answer sheet in offline quiz

Tags: php, moodle

I am new to moodle and using moodle 2.5. Trying to figure out how offline quiz works. But i am getting error while uploading Answer sheet to offline quiz. help please, i am new to moodle.

> Importing 1 to 1 of 1. Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1467 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1470 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1470 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1475 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1476 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,794 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,795 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,796 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,797 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,798 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,799 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,800 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,801 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,802 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,803 is out of bounds in
>   C:\inetpub\wwwroot\elms\mod\offlinequiz\report\rimport\scanner.php on
>   line 1089 Notice: imagecolorat(): -9,804 is out of bounds in 
>   Cont.....

Comment: This is a plugin rather than Moodle code - the plugin is over here https://moodle.org/plugins/view/mod_offlinequiz : Can you first check you are using the latest version for 2.5 - in mod/offlinequiz/version.php it should be $plugin->version  = 2012052001;

Comment: This plugin is has version:             $module->version  = 2014033100;
$module->release   = "2014-03-31";  is it old version? not compatible to Moodle 2.5?  yes this plugin is downloaded from  [ moodle.org/plugins/view/mod_offlinequiz ]  page only.

Comment: That version might have been developed for 2.7, I'm not sure - https://github.com/academic-moodle-cooperation/moodle-mod_offlinequiz/blob/5dbf36388eea93f09c3bedfb06dcc77b9e993f8e/version.php - maybe try downloading the version for 2.5 to see if it works or the latest version for 2.7 which is "2014092301" - https://moodle.org/plugins/view/ mod_offlinequiz